# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance:(View: C:\Laravel5.8\nblog\resources\views\content\emailsForReview.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is the controller

```
public function emailsForReview()
{
    $email= Email::all();
    return view('content.emailsForReview',compact('email'));
}
```

this is the blade

```
@foreach($email as $emails)
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="md-form mb-0">
          <label for="name" class="">name</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{$email->name}}" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
         </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

this is the route

```
Route::get('/emailsForReview','PagesController@emailsForReview');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Should be `$emails->name`.

Edit 1
as **@ceejayoz** suggested, in you controller switch this line:
`return view('content.emailsForReview',compact('email'));` to `return view('content.emailsForReview',compact('emails'));`

In blade view, in your foreach use `@foreach($emails as $email)` and retrieve data like `$email->name` inside the cycle. Will be more clear to distinguish.

Comment: Better yet, switch `$email` and `$emails` throughout to properly reflect the actual plurality.

Answer (score 0):

convert your blade code from

```
@foreach($email as $emails)
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="md-form mb-0">
          <label for="name" class="">name</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{$email->name}}" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
         </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($email as $emails)
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="md-form mb-0">
          <label for="name" class="">name</label>
          <input type="text" value="{{$emails->name}}" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
         </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Notice the difference when calling the name. using $emails->name not $email->name